# Strength training gym equipment exercise rotation

Tags: exercise, strength, strength-training, sports

I started going to gym with my wife and we are focusing on strength exercise. We do rotations (by doing 5-8 times on max weight we can do for that specific muscle training) on each gym apparatus then moving to next one until we are done with all gym equipment. We then take a 5-10 minute break and do another round. 3 rounds in total which usually take 90-100 minutes in total including resting. I also try to switch between arms and legs to give more rest to muscles. I have noticed that some people that are coming to gym (that do seem quite fit) do same type of muscle training 3 times on one machine and only then move to different one. The way I understand muscle growth is all about ripping the muscles not tiring them out.

**Which way is better for strength: do one type of training at once or rotate different ones and save time needed for resting (or neither)?**

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question to Fitness since I think it would be a better fit there.

Comment: What is "overall training?". I can say this is not optimal for strength.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### To get strong, lift heavy

By constantly moving on you elevate your heart rate and fatigue takes over. Don't think of your muscles getting fatigue but instead think of your whole body. For example, deadlift and bench press use completely different muscle groups but you won't find anyone going to do a set of heavy deadlifts after a heavy bench set. What you are doing is basically **circuit training**, still a valid activity but you aren't going to "get strong".

Your definition of strength may be different but most common one is "ability to move something heavy, once". Your routine develops muscular endurance.

#### Which way is better for strength: do one type of training at once or rotate different ones and save time needed for resting (or neither)?

**Neither**. You need compound movements, drop the machines and pick up a barbell. Squat, deadlift, press.

Answer (score 3):

What you are currently doing sounds like it will keep you very well rounded and fit but not so much specific muscle strength.

It is generally agreed that doing multiple sets e.g. 3-5 of a number of reps 5-15 on the same muscle group or piece of equipment is optimal for strength training.

"Progressive overload is one of the basic principles of strength training and basically means that you have to increase the weight, intensity and/or number of repetitions/sets to create an adaptive response." - [bretcontreras.com](https://bretcontreras.com/10-keys-to-optimal-strength-training/)

One of the most popular strength training programs is called 5x5, in which you do 5 sets of 5 reps with as much as weight as you can do safely on one piece of equipment e.g. bench press. On this kind of program you wouldnt be doing many different exercises per day though e.g. 3. ([stronglifts.com](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/) is an example of such a routine)

But at the end of the day it is really what you prefer doing and if you specifically want to get stronger at something doing more than 1 set will help you do that.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your post and welcome to Health SE! Here post generally have references to verify content. Adding this would allow your post to follow site guidelines. Thank you!